# Two jQuery dialogs with different themes in the same page

Tags: jquery, dialog, themes

I want to have two dialogs with different themes in the same page, but it doesn't work correctly. What am I doing wrong?
My problem and my code you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/HBPBc/2/

I want if I push link with id="dialog_link_1" popup dialog with blitzer theme and if I push link with id="dialog_link_2" popup dialog with redmond theme.

I understand that on the second dialog wrap again make the wrap first dialog .ui-dialog, but how to distinguish them completely to the idea of ​​a specific dialogue.

Comment: I think you will get more help if you actually explain what you are trying to accomplish in this question, instead of with just a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Use the http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-dialogClass option to toggle the themes

http://jsfiddle.net/kannix/HBPBc/4/

Comment: ok... i try, but it is not good.... dialog titlebar and buttonbar they will be don't correctly and IE scrol always run (sense, it is still lower).

Comment: that seems to be a general jquery dialog bug..but i fixed it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HBPBc/5/ you can read more about it here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/opening-a-modal-dialog-shows-a-horizontal-scroll-bar

Comment: best solution is wrap(), since the running and draggable and resizable but how to make the creation of a second dialogue would not change nothing for the first

Answer (score 0):

solution is I found it: add required class and remove do not necessarily when open dialog
http://jsfiddle.net/HBPBc/6/